# Getting radius in meters/km from latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta

Tags: mysql, laravel, react-native, latitude-longitude, react-native-maps

I am requesting data from backend (laravel) based on a set distance between 2 points `latitude` and `longitude` eg. Lat= 78.3232 and Long = 65.3234 and distance = 30 miles/kilometers , get the rows within the 30 miles.

The problem I'm having is with `distance`.

I am using `react-native-maps` and the zoom in/out is based on the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` and I don't know how to calculate the radius/distance of them when the user zooms in/out to be sent to the backend and get data based on the points and radius/distance

at the moment, I have this function on the client-side. to determine when to fetch new data when user changes the region. but it has a problem of hard-coded `distance` (5.0 KM)

```
const _onRegionChangeComplete = (onCompletedregion: Region) => {
    if (initialRegion) {
      const KMDistance = helper.distance(         
        initialRegion?.latitude,
        initialRegion?.longitude,
        onCompletedregion.latitude,
        onCompletedregion.longitude,
        "K"
      );

      if (KMDistance > 5.0) {
        props.getNearByReports({   // request backend if distance difference more than 5 kilometers
          latitude: onCompletedregion.latitude,
          longitude: onCompletedregion.longitude
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

helper.distance // get the difference in distance between the initial points and after the user done changing the region

```
function distance(
  lat1: number,
  lon1: number,
  lat2: number,
  lon2: number,
  unit: string
) {
  var radlat1 = (Math.PI * lat1) / 180;
  var radlat2 = (Math.PI * lat2) / 180;
  var theta = lon1 - lon2;
  var radtheta = (Math.PI * theta) / 180;
  var dist =
    Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) +
    Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = (dist * 180) / Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  if (unit == "K") {
    dist = dist * 1.609344;
  }
  if (unit == "M") {
    dist = dist * 0.8684;
  }
  return dist;
}
```

The `distance` value is hard coded in the backend and frontend (which shouldn't be) cuz when the user zooms in/out , the radius/distance should change too. I am unable to calculate the distance from `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`

// Backend query code (simplified)

```
SELECT
  id, (
    6371 * acos (   
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 5 // hard-coded distance
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, how to calculate radius/distance of the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta! Or maybe im getting this all wrong and I should approach this differently. not sure

Comment: But that is what your code does , right?

Comment: The code at the moment doesn't take into account `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`, and neither the backend does, and I have hardcoded them to my desired values / zoom. this works fine as long the user doesn't zoom out. if he drags the map to a different region, the request to fetch data kicks off (when drag distance is above 5 KM).but if the user zooms out, then a small amount of drag to the map produces a huge distance difference ( > 5). this is pushing to think that I should fetch my data based on something other than distance or the distance should be dynamically set and sent to backend

Comment: so when the user zooms out, I should somehow translate that to more distance, eg. 50 KM , and the backend fetches data surrounding 50 KM radius, I hope this is clear now

Comment: 'cleared the air' means 'to say conciliatory words after having an argument'

Comment: I guess I puzzled by the fact that we seem to have a fontend function and a backend function which are both doing the same thing !?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`latitudeDelta` is the amount of `degrees` that are visible on the screen. `1 degree` is always equal to approx. `69 miles`, so you can calculate the diameter of the currently visible area in miles with this `diameter = latitudeDelta * 69`. This is assuming the screen is in portrait mode and, therefore, `latitudeDelta` is the larger value. If not, use `longitudeDelta` instead. I hope I understood your question correctly and this is helpful.

Comment: I guess this is what I wanted, it wasn't clear to me what the latitudeDelta actually represented. I just hope your answer is correct. I tested it out and it seems it gives the  diameter value of the visible area on screen upon zooming in/out. thank you

Comment: If that is on a sphere, you need to adjust the longitudeDelta by cos(latitude).